# Cant figure out why strings do not strictly equate

Tags: javascript

I have been working on the speed at which I solve problems. Im aware this implementation isn't great, but I'm wondering why these two strings will not equate to each other. Im guessing theres an extra space somewhere that Im missing, but i don't have enough experience to be able to implement a method to find the problem. I have already completed the problem with another method but the issue with this one is still bothering me. Could someone explain to me what I am missing here?

```
function renderInventory(inventory) {
  var result = '';
  var resultArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < inventory.length; i++){
    var moveOut = inventory[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < inventory[i]['shoes'].length; j++){
      var lineItemArray = [];
      lineItemArray.push(moveOut['name']);
      lineItemArray.push(moveOut['shoes'][j]['name']);
      lineItemArray.push(moveOut['shoes'][j]['price']+"\n");
      resultArray.push(lineItemArray);
    }
  }
  for (var k = 0; k < resultArray.length; k++){
    resultArray[k] = resultArray[k].join(' - ');
  }
  result = resultArray.join('');
  return result;
}
//ASSERTION
function assertEquals (actual, expected, testName){
  if (actual === expected){
    console.log(`PASSED!!!   \nON: ${testName}   \n\nE:\n${expected}\n\n === \n\nA:\n${actual}`);
  }else{
    console.log(`FAILURE...   \nON: ${testName}   \n\nE:\n${expected}\n\n !== \n\nA:\n${actual}`);
  }
}
//TEST VARIABLES
var currentInventory = [
  {
    name: 'Brunello Cucinelli',
    shoes: [
      {name: 'tasselled black low-top lace-up', price: 1000},
      {name: 'tasselled green low-top lace-up', price: 1100},
      {name: 'plain beige suede moccasin', price: 950},
      {name: 'plain olive suede moccasin', price: 1050}
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Gucci',
    shoes: [
      {name: 'red leather laced sneakers', price: 800},
      {name: 'black leather laced sneakers', price: 900}
    ]
  }
];
var output = 
"Brunello Cucinelli - tasselled black low-top lace-up - 1000\nBrunello Cucinelli - tasselled green low-top lace-up - 1100\nBrunello Cucinelli - plain beige suede moccasin - 950\nBrunello Cucinelli - plain olive suede moccasin - 1050\nGucci - red leather laced sneakers - 800\nGucci - black leather laced sneakers - 900";
//TEST SPACE

assertEquals (renderInventory(currentInventory), output, 'testSetInventory');
```

Comment: You can use `console.log()` to output the value of variables or functions, and then you can eyeball them to see if they contain what you expected. For example `console.log(renderInventory(currentInventory))`

Comment: Looks to me like output does not end in /n but resultarray does. But also you're comparing a string and an array. resultArray = resultArray.join('');
  return resultArray; should be result = resultArray.join('');
  return result;

Comment: @JeremyKahan YOU SIR! thank you! post as answer and ill credit you if you'd like... should have better checked the test output for errors rather than being so sure i made a mistake in the implementation

Comment: Take a look at this line: `lineItemArray.push(moveOut['shoes'][j]['price']+"\n");` After each price there is a new line in the rendered string but the last newline is missing in the expected outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw two issues that could be messing things up.

1. The variable `output` does not end in `\n` but the last `lineItem` will.
2. You were comparing a string and an array.

   ```
   resultArray = resultArray.join(''); 
   return resultArray;
   ```

   should have been

   ```
   result = resultArray.join(''); 
   return result;
   ```

Comment: the type of `resultArray` was actually of type string, i just forgot to return the correct `result` variable. But you found the problem none the less, the final `\n` was the issue and i was doing the majority of my checking in `console.log()`

Comment: oh, okay, my bad. I suppose it would reset itself to match what you assigned it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this line:

```
lineItemArray.push(moveOut['shoes'][j]['price']+"\n");
```

After each price there is a new line in the rendered string but the last newline is missing in the expected outcome.

Check it working after I added a newline to `var output`: https://repl.it/repls/WonderfulRedParameter

---

Using the original value of `output`, the function `renderInventory()` can be simplified:

```
function renderInventory(inventory) {
  var resultArray = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < inventory.length; i++){
    var moveOut = inventory[i];

    for (var j = 0; j < moveOut['shoes'].length; j++){
      var lineItemArray = [];
      lineItemArray.push(moveOut['name']);
      lineItemArray.push(moveOut['shoes'][j]['name']);
      lineItemArray.push(moveOut['shoes'][j]['price']);
      resultArray.push(lineItemArray.join(' - '));
    }
  }

  return resultArray.join('\n');
}
```

and more:

```
function renderInventory(inventory) {
  return inventory.map((moveOut) => {
    return moveOut['shoes'].map((item) => {
      return [
        moveOut['name'],
        item['name'],
        item['price']
      ].join(' - ');
    }).join('\n');
  }).join('\n');
}
```

Comment: I like the inclusion of the running code and the simplification.